# Quickest way to plot ~400,000 points in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, large-data

I have a list which contains some data points which I need to plot.

The list is approximately 11,000 x 40 in size (2D Plot with numeric values).

Currently I am using matplotlib (as I moved to python from Matlab), however this is slow to plot so many points, and resizing the graph manually crashes my computer (MacBook Retina with 16Gb RAM).

The graph I would like needs to be interactive and therefore such delays are unacceptable.

Can anyone give me some advice with regards to perhaps a better (quicker) plotting library?

Thanks

EDIT: I am currently researching some tools but I am finding it difficult to work out which would be the fastest in terms of plotting...

I am looking at:

MathGL - http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/

Gnuplot.py - http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/

PyQtGraph  - http://www.pyqtgraph.org/

PyQwt - http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/

guiqwt - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/guiqwt/

Comment: How big is the target image? Is it necessary to plot every single point? Would the image look very different if you took a sub-sampling of points? Can you cluster and average the data to reduce the number of points plotted?

Comment: The target image needs to contain every point, I cannot take a sample of points nor can I average/cluster the points. Basically the way my software is designed to work is it will plot every point and then the user can set thresholds to fade plots from the image that don't match what they are interested in... The reason for fading is because it allows the relativity of the data they are interested in to the whole data to remain...

Comment: So *after* the user specifies thresholds, the image is much easier to plot? If so, perhaps *only* display the graph with some default and adjustable threshold. Don't let the threshold be so large that you have to plot 400K points all at once. If the data has very disparate values, it probably would not be comprehensible to look at anyway. If the data has slowly varying values, then you should be able to cluster and average to summarize the data.

Comment: you want want 11k lines that are 40 points long, or a 11k by 4k image?

Comment: @tcaswell It has 11k lines that are 40 points long

Comment: @unutbu I will have to discuss this at my meeting tomorrow to see what I should do.

Comment: and do you want to fade _lines_ or _points_?  Do you expect a marker on each point?

Comment: and as this question stands it is off topic because you are primarily asking for tool suggestions, not how to make your mpl solution faster.

Comment: Well I'm not sure whether to change tools or make my mpl solution faster. Basically if I change tools I need to have the functionality to be able to make the graph interactive which is why I wrote that in my question. I need to fade both lines and points although I guess I don't need a marker for each point so long as I have the line and the user could then hover over a point for the specific co-ordinates.

Comment: Would you mind updating your question to your current needs - I'm not sure there is enough information there for anybody to help you. For instance, could you mock up some data and an example of the kind of plot you are trying to create (more efficiently)?